# Botframework LUIS dialog throwing HttpException on initialization

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I create a new Cognitive Service through Azure in Southeast Asia and am now trying to connect to it through Botframework.

I specified the endpoint in the attribute, but throws a 400 error.

```
[Serializable]
[LuisModel("My modelID", "My Acces Key",  domain: "southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com")]
public class LuisTowelDialog : LuisDialog<OrderEnumModel>
{
    //implementation here
}
```

How do I set this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to Train and then publish my LUIS instance first.